# Monotonic Transformation and Optimization

Tags: optimization

Let us consider the following function $f:X\rightarrow{R}$.
Let us denote by $f_{max}$ and $f_{min}$, respectively, maximum and minimum values of $f$ function. 
Let us consider the following monotonic function $g:X\rightarrow{R}$.
By using monotonic transformation of $f$ we obtain the following function $h:X\rightarrow{R}$, where $h=g(f)$. Let us denote by  $h_{max}$ and $h_{min}$, respectively, maximum and minimum values of $h$ function.

What is the relationship between   $f_{max}$ and $h_{max}$ and  $f_{min}$ and $h_{min}$?

P.S. I know that for monotonic transformation the extreme values match. In what cases it is true?

Comment: Do you mean $g\colon{\Bbb R}\to {\Bbb R}$? It is easy to see that the optimal solutions, if exists, $x_{opt}$ are the same for $f$ and $h$.

Comment: The question can be transformed in the following way: what is the relationship between $f(x_{max})$ and $h(x_{max})$? That is, what is the relationship between $f$ and $h$ functions' extreme values?